# How to change Flutter TextField underline color from blue to grey?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to change the default blue underline color of a Flutter TextField to grey while keeping the current underline-only style.

[image: Image illustrating the current blue underline and desired gray]

**Code:**

```
class test extends StatefulWidget {
  const test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<test> createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF6F6F6),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Enter email",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 350,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted,
                        decorationColor: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Things I've Tried:**

I've explored using `borderSide` and `borderRadius`, but these solutions modify TextField's appearance beyond just the color. I want to retain the simple underline style.

**Specific Question:**

How can I change TextField's underline color to grey without affecting its design?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
```